# Where can I find output log file of a setup generated by IExpress

Tags: batch-file, iexpress

I have a exe file created via IExpress. This file contains 1 msi file, 1 setup.exe file and a batch file with those commands:

```
C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe /i pitming.msi /passive
setup.exe
```

When I manually launch the batch, everything runs fine. But once I put everithing in the exe, nothing happen. So I'm trying to find what is wrong, but I don't know where to find a log file containning the error.

Can someone help ?

Thx,

Comment: The problems seem to be that the cmd.exe that should launch my batch file is not the one from c:\windows\system32 but some old one. So I call my batch file this way and everything works fine: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c  FullInstall.bat

Answer (score 1):

If you want the log out of the MSI you need to edit the line to:

```
C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe /i pitming.msi /passive /l*v %temp%\pitming.log
```

and you'll at least get some logging out of it.

What command are you using to launch the batch file? You might find that you need to make the post install command to be:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c mybatchfile.bat
```

As far as the setup.exe goes, that probably has its own logging options.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that when running batch files with IExpress, it's best to call `cmd.exe` explicitly; if you don't, you seem to wind up with `command.com` (which doesn't work very well). However `cmd /c` is probably better.